# Finding the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2- \frac 1 {4n} \right )^n $

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit: $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2- \frac 1 {4n} \right )^n  $$

I checked with W/A and it should go to infinity, I also noticed if it was $\left(1- \frac 1 {4n} \right )^n$ then it wouldn't go to infinity which is interesting, is there some general theorem that states that if it's bigger than 1 than it must tend to infinity?

Anyway, I tried to use the binomial to show the limit is infinity but I get alternating signs so that won't help, I don't have any other idea... Any hint please?

Note: no integrals/derivatives.

Comment: Did you notice that the base of the exponential tends to 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a>1$ and $b>0$ than $a-\frac bn>1$ for $n$ large enough, say for $n\ge n_0$. Moreover, with $q:=a-\frac b{n_0}>1$, we have $\left(a-\frac bn\right)^n\ge q^n$ for $n\ge n_0$. As already $q^n\to+\infty$, this shows that $\left(a-\frac bn\right)^n\to +\infty$ as well.

On the other hand, one can show that $\left(1-\frac bn\right)^n\to e^{-b}$.

Comment: Ah very cool, this explains the general case nicely. Proving for $a<1$ is similar I assume.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\displaystyle 2 - \frac{1}{4n} > \frac{3}{2}$ for all positive integers $n$. Hence

$$\left(2 - \frac{1}{4n}\right)^n > \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$ and the term on the RHS diverges.

Comment: So simple... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$2-\dfrac1{4n} > \dfrac32$$
Now conclude what you want.